# Reload View by Clicking on TabBarItem (Cause of PDF)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, pdf, uiwebview, uitabbaritem

I have a Tab Bar Controller with 4 Items. In the 4 one I included a webView with some links. One of the links is a PDF, if I open a PDF in the webView there is no way to go back to the main webView with the links.
Is there a way by re-clicking the 4. TabBar to reload the View? If I change from the 3. to the 4. tabbar it works (viewWillAppear). ![enter image description here][1]

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this method of ([UITabBarControllerDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/ipad/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITabBarControllerDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html)):

(maybe something like this)

```
- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController{
        //Try this if you're pushing the webView in another ViewController
        [viewController.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
        //or access to your webView and call goBack();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a method in UITabBarDelegate called:

```
- (void)tabBar:(UITabBar *)tabBar didSelectItem:(UITabBarItem *)item;
```

You could use that to also catch touches of the selected tab bar item.